# Audio Qml Failure

Tags: qt, audio, qml

I'm trying to add background music to a small application. I'm using Window7 and MinGW but I get this error:

> ASSERT: "!url.isRelative() && (QQmlFile::urlToLocalFileOrQrc(url).isEmpty() || !QDir::isRelativePath(QQmlFile::urlToLocalFileOrQrc(url)))" in file qml\qqmltypeloader.cpp, line 1639
>   Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
>   Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

This is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.8

Rectangle {
    id: main
    width: 600
    height: 400
    state: "mainMenu"
    property int margePixel: 30
    property int tailleInfoJeux: 200

    Image {
        id: background
        source:"qrc:/images/mainbkg"
        anchors.fill: parent
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        sourceSize.height: 800
    }

    MediaPlayer{
        id: musicBkg
        source: "file:///Users/COMPUTER/Documents/candycrush/candy-crush-like-master/sound/bkg1.wav"
        autoLoad: true
        autoPlay: false
        volume: 1.0
        loops: Audio.Infinite

        Component.onCompleted: {
            //console.log(source==Qt.resolvedUrl("file:///Users/COMPUTER/Documents/candycrush/candy-crush-like-master/sound/Kalimba.mp3"))
            console.log(musicBkg.supportedAudioRoles())
        }
    }
}
```

this is the .pro file

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/SweetCandy
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    bonbon.cpp \
    niveau.cpp \
    case.cpp \
    controleur.cpp

# Installation path
# target.path =
QT += multimedia
# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

OTHER_FILES += \
    qml/SweetCandy/main.qml \
    qml/SweetCandy/VueBonbon.qml \
    qml/SweetCandy/VueCase.qml

HEADERS += \
    bonbon.h \
    niveau.h \
    case.h \
    controleur.h

RESOURCES += \
    ressources.qrc

ICON = SweetCandyIconeLinux.png
macx: ICON = SweetCandyIconeMac.icns
win32: RC_FILE = SweetCandy.rc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
source: "file:///c:\Users\COMPUTER\Documents\candycrush\candy-crush-like-master\sound\bkg1.wav"
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply. I tried with your suggestion but it doesn't work. It gives:DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80040216 ()

Comment: it is either url problem or codec problem. Can you please check that wav file directory and also extension. if you are %100 sure that url is correct than you should change to mp3 and try again. if mp3 is working that means there is missing codec at your system.

Comment: The Url i think is correct, i tried with Qt.resolvedUrl(...) and it returns true, I tried also with mp3 and ogg, same result

Comment: Could you provide project's .pro file please?